# Url Rewriting in Umbraco 5 Jupiter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, umbraco5

i want to do simple URL re-writing in Umbraco 5 like we used to do in previous versions i-e changing the UrlRewriting.config file, or we used to do it in Asp .Net

```
<rewriter>
 <rewrite url="~/en/faq.aspx" to="~/faq.aspx" />
</rewrite>
```

I know we can create new area in the application and then add new routes in areaRegisteration.cs. but then the problem of mapping these controllers to the default Views arises, as the views are in:  Views > Umbraco Directory of the application.

For example,

I create a new Area Named "En" and add Route in EngAreaRegisteration.cs, i-e

```
context.MapRoute("en_property","en/{city}/{controller}/{action}",new {  } );
```

then how i can map the Actions to any Umbraco Page, i dont think the Redirect is a solution as redirect will change the Url,

my URL will be like this, en/paris/property/book

i am using Umbraco 5.0.1 Web deploy.

Thanks in Advance

Sher